Does the lowest tranche in a collateralized loan obligation have duration? If so, what it is?
In a Collateralized Loan Obligation, the lowest tranche ("equity CLO") bears most of the risk as it covers for any losses first and gets paid last -- it however has the highest upside since it gets "the residual" which could possibly be a lot, both from the coupons and from the value of the underlying loans.
The higher tranches have spread duration - but it seems natural to me that the lowest tranche also has spread duration; after all, if spreads rise, then this correlated with defaults, missing coupon payments, etc., all of which hurt the lowest tranche.
However googling I cannot find any notion of spread duration for the equity tranche? Yet to me it seems like the most meaningful number to capture its risk.
